# What is difference between VMX and VT-x?

Tags: virtualization, vt-x

lscpu commands gives me

```
Virtualization:                  VT-x
```

but it also gives:-

```
Vulnerability Itlb multihit:     KVM: Mitigation: VMX disabled
```

I searched google and found out that I have to enable VMX in bios. will it affect VT-x ? and will I get any benefits by enabling it?

Answer (score 2):

> I searched google and found out that I have to enable VMX in bios. will it affect VT-x ? and will I get any benefits by enabling it?

The CPU flag for Intel Hardware Virtualization is VMX.  VT-x is Intel Hardware Virtualization which means they are exactly the same.  **You change the value of the CPU flag by enabling or disabling VT-x within BIOS.**  If there isn't an option to enable VT-x within the firmware for your device then it cannot be enabled.

> The CPU flag for VT-x capability is "vmx"; in Linux, this can be checked via /proc/cpuinfo
>
> "VMX" stands for Virtual Machine Extensions, which adds 13 new instructions: VMPTRLD, VMPTRST, VMCLEAR, VMREAD, VMWRITE, VMCALL, VMLAUNCH, VMRESUME, VMXOFF, VMXON, INVEPT, INVVPID, and VMFUNC.  These instructions permit entering and exiting a virtual execution mode where the guest OS perceives itself as running with full privilege (ring 0), but the host OS remains protected.
>
> The CPU flag for AMD-V is "svm" in Linux via /proc/cpuinfo.[19] Instructions in AMD-V include VMRUN, VMLOAD, VMSAVE, CLGI, VMMCALL, INVLPGA, SKINIT, and STGI.

Source: [Intel virtualization (VT-x)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_virtualization)

Comment: Wouldn't this imply the lscpu output is possibly broken on some deeper level? Given your explanation, it seems quite odd that it can state VT-x as available in one line, yet claim VMX instructions are disabled in another.

Comment: @E.T. - Trying to determine if the output of lscpu is broken is beyond the scope of my answer. Since CPU flag for VT-x is VMX you can make your own conclusions.  Looking back at the year old question, the output seems to simply suggest that KVM is disabled, but I am not that familiar with lscpu. However, I don't have to be familiar, since my answer directly answers the author's question about enabling VT-x